# Capturing events whenever a new thread starts or ends in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a highly multithreaded application , where threads are started from multiple places and i would like to know if i can hook into the running process and just get alerted whenever a new Managed Thread is spawned. I should be able to get the following information

1. The parent thread
2. New thread
3. the method from which the new thread is started like `<className>.<methodName>`

The application is in C# 3.5

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. You can use `Threads` property of the `Process` object to get all current threads of the process, but that's about it. What about having a wrapper class that would be used across the application to start threads? You could put whatever tracking logic you need there.

Comment: @NikolaAnusev, the Threads property returns native threads, not managed threads

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to do things this way? I think I would just use the ThreadPool class and forget this nonsense.

Comment: This is an existing application and im trying to understand how it works. Will CLR Profiling APIs help?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal +1, yes.  I have never needed to know this kind of information.  Normally, any thread I use is either pooled or is dedicated and runs for the lifetime of the app.  If I only create threads at app startup, I don't need to inspect/log any thread info during the run.  In fact, I would run away from any attempt to do such a thing.  The very thought of a 'Thread Manager' class is horrifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State should be handle within the thread processing logic.

I suggest you create a wrapper class which wraps the thread logic and reports it's status and other items as needed. I created such a class for a multi-threaded application where I could corral the status of the threads and pipe that information to the GUI in a standardized way.

Of course I had the luxury of designing it up front, to which, you may not have.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know there is no way to detect when a thread starts. The best solution is probably not to create thread directly, but instead do it via a "thread manager" class that will raise an event when it starts a thread.

Comment: +1 for the first part. but noting that the thread manager may not work for cases where threads are started by third party objects.